# Get notified about dragged images within a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript

I have a div which has contenteditable="true" and which contains some html. This html may include images.

Since contenteditable="true" the user can move images by dragging them to a new position. But I need my code to be notified each time a image is moved, in a way where I get both the image element which is being moved, and the target node where the image is dropped. How do I do that?

My current solution adds a Drop listener to my div element which is contenteditable, and then I do get a drop event each time the user moves an image, but I can't get the dom node with the image which the user moved.

Also: Dragging an image, seems to copy the DOM node, instead of moving it. Is this true? (Tested in firefox).

Comment: you show us your code and if you really want to make us happy you even create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: a jsfiddle Is a bit complicated, because I am using gwt(Googles java to javascript compiler). So my current almost working solution is written in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest a following pure JavaScript solution

HTML:

```
<div id="space" contenteditable="true">
  Hello <img width="300" class="contentImg" src='http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article9859555.ece/alternates/w620/Dr-Talyor.jpg'/> dude!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#space {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var draggedImg;
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
    // IE uses srcElement, others use target
    var targ = event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement;
    if (targ.className == 'contentImg'){
      draggedImg = event.target;
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragend", function( event ) {
    if(draggedImg){
      alert("It's moved!");
      console.log('Here is data', draggedImg);
      draggedImg = null;
    }
}, false);
```

You'll find an image node in draggedImg variable.

Please review a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/o09hLtch/2/

Comment: I like the concept, but if I try the example in the jsfiddle and move the picture 20 pixel to the left i get this is my console:

Comment: I like the concept, and it seems to work. Just a quick note: you should move the alert down below draggedImg = null, otherwise you get infinite recursion in firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the note. This alert is just a way to show a message about the event. Can be easily removed or replaced by console.log, or by any other logic to handle this event.

Answer (score 0):

[jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/) features [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) interactions. Draggable has [drag event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag), which gives you the dragged element and droppable has [drop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop), which gives you the dropped element as well as where it was dropped.

Quick example: [clickety](https://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/691cg1ee/)

```
$('#content .dr').draggable(
{
    addClasses: false,
    drag: function(event, ui)
    {
        $('#notify').text('Bird (#' + $(this).attr('id') + ') being dragged: ' + JSON.stringify(ui));
    },
    stop: function(event, ui)
    {
        $('#notify').text('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You looking for this,

```
$(function () {
 $(".image").draggable({helper: 'original'});
    $(".container").droppable({
      drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable.css({position: 'static'}));
        alert('dropped!');
    }
 });
});
```

For JSFiddle Demo [Let's see](http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/P6TjC/)

Good Luck ['}